# Making waves from letters with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wave

I am trying to make waves from letters on hover using jQuery and its plugin called lettering.js, which spans every letter of a element.
[This is what I tried to do [*http://jsbin.com/ezuze*])](http://jsbin.com/ezuzep)
I am newb and tried using `for` loop, but failed :(. Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please improve your question? It's not clear what you want to achieve or what results you've had thus far.

Comment: @NathanTaylor: Click on the link and explain to the OP why his code is broken. It's a fairly common problem.

Comment: @Blender Be my guest. I'm just trying to encourage him to ask better questions. :\

Comment: Well, I can see one problem where you use `i*100`. Have a read, its one of the finer details in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 2):

The `animate()` function is being used incorrectly ([demo](http://jsbin.com/ezuzep/3))

```
$(function() {
  $('h1').lettering();
  $('h1 span')
    .css('position','relative')
    .hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({ top:'10px' }, 100);
    }, function(){
      $(this).animate({ top: 0 }, 100);
    });

});
```

And no loop is required, unless you want to animate ALL of the spans upon initial hover.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/ezuzep/4/edit

Using the inbuilt `.each()` function is better for new players, since loops can get quite confusing.